# How do I change flutter_ling version in flutter project?

Tags: firebase, flutter, flutter-file

Here I trying to add dependency

```
geoflutterfire: ^3.0.3
```

After adding this line in `pubspec.yml` I presses pub get to get all package which I listed in it.
But I got an error something about `flutter_lint` version

```
Running "flutter pub get" in example...
Because example depends on geoflutterfire ^3.0.3 which depends on flutter_lints ^1.0.0, flutter_lints ^1.0.0 is required.
So, because example depends on flutter_lints ^2.0.0, version solving failed.
pub get failed (1; So, because example depends on flutter_lints ^2.0.0, version solving failed.)
```

Comment: can you share the snapshot of pubspec.yaml file

Comment: did you tried to add dependency of flutter_lints:^2.0.0 manually?

Comment: yes I already tried

Comment: you should add `flutter_lints: ^1.0.0` not 2, if its added already then downgrade its version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced the same problem and solved it by downgrading this version of **geoflutterfire: ^3.0.3** to **geoflutterfire: ^3.0.2.**
I hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrading version of geoflutterfire: ^3.0.3 to geoflutterfire: ^3.0.2 will cause multiple errors if you are using firebase_core and cloud_firestore. What worked for me was that I used geoflutterfire2. It has pub point 140/140 and hopefully will work for you as well